# Extract particular words from a txt file using python

Tags: python-3.x

I need some help using Python in order to extract from a txt file a particular part.
Indeed, I would like from the following file to extract only the part with `Organism :` 
But without keeping the part between the "`()`".

In this exemple it would give:

```
Select item 1949871
1.

Amel_HAv3.1

Organism:
    Apis mellifera (honey bee)

Infraspecific name:
    Strain: DH4

Sex:
    male

Submitter:
    Uppsala University

Date:
    2018/09/10

Assembly level:
    Chromosome

Genome representation:
    full

RefSeq category:
    representative genome

GenBank assembly accession:
    GCA_003254395.2 (latest) 

RefSeq assembly accession:
    GCF_003254395.2 (latest) 

IDs:
    1949871 [UID] 7372188 [GenBank] 7434688 [RefSeq]

Select item 2027291
2.

Obir_v5.4

Organism:
    Ooceraea biroi (clonal raider ant)

Submitter:
    The Rockefeller University

Date:
    2018/10/23

Assembly level:
    Chromosome

Genome representation:
    full

RefSeq category:
    representative genome

GenBank assembly accession:
    GCA_003672135.1 (latest) 

RefSeq assembly accession:
    GCF_003672135.1 (latest) 

IDs:
    2027291 [UID] 7620928 [GenBank] 7654158 [RefSeq]

Select item 1769491
3.

Nlec1.1

Organism:
    Neodiprion lecontei (redheaded pine sawfly)

Sex:
    male

Submitter:
    University of Kentucky

Date:
    2018/06/21

Assembly level:
    Chromosome

Genome representation:
    full

RefSeq category:
    representative genome

GenBank assembly accession:
    GCA_001263575.2 (latest) 

RefSeq assembly accession:
    n/a

IDs:
    1769491 [UID] 6705508 [GenBank] 

Select item 294348
4.

Bter_1.0
```

and I would like in python to only keep the part after Organism: (without the part between "`()`") and get for this exemple:

```
Apis mellifera
Neodiprion lecontei
Ooceraea biroi
```

Does someone have an idea please?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a more complete snippet, using [regex](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/re.html) (without omitting the multiline flag):

```
import re

with open("your_file.txt", "r") as f:
    content = f.read()

    matches = re.findall(r"Organism:\s*(.+)\s*\(", content, re.M)

for m in matches:
    print(m)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple [regex](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/re.html) for this:

```py
re.findall(r'Organism:\n\s*(.*) \(', text)
```

Comment: Thank you but I get the error : `>>> re.findall(r'Organism:\n\s*(.*) \(', f)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/beegfs/data/soft/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/re.py", line 223, in findall
    return _compile(pattern, flags).findall(string)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object.`    the f is a txt file open with :  `f = open("directory/tax_name_genomes.txt","r")`

Comment: Try using `f.read()` to read the data out of the file, rather than using the file handle itself in `findall`.